# Show that $\lim [(2n)^\frac{1}{n})] = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-theorem

Prove that $\lim ((2n)^\frac{1}{n}) = 1$.

I have obtained the following:

$$(2n)^\frac{1}{n} = 1 + k_{n}; n > 1$$
$$(2n) = (1 + k_{n})^n$$

By the Binomial Theorem:
$$(1 + k_{n})^n = 1 + k_{n} + \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)k_{n}^2 + ...$$

So
$$2n > \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)k_{n}^2$$
$$k_{n} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{n-1}}$$

However, I am not sure how to simplify this down to show $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n-1}} < \varepsilon, \forall \varepsilon > 0$ e.g. by invoking say $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n-1}} < \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$

Comment: Whenever you fix $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $n$ such that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n-1}} < \varepsilon$, just take the square of both sides and find $n$. So you should be done.

Comment: It would be nice if you let us know what is the variable in the expression and at which value of the variable the limit should be evaluated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$1<(2n)^{\frac{1}{n}}<1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$$ works because by the binomial theorem  we obtain:
$$\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n>1+2\sqrt{n}+\frac{4}{n}\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=2\sqrt{n}+2n-1>2n.$$
Now, $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$ for $n>\frac{4}{\epsilon^2}.$

Answer (score 5):

I will prove a nice theorem that is known as the Cauchy-D'Alembert criterion in my country(I have yet to find any references to it in English,so if you have any I would appreciate if you shared them with me).
**Theorem** : Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers such that $\exists \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$. Then we have $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n] x_n =\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$
*Proof*: Denote $L=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n] x_n$
$=>\ln L=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln x_n}{n}=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln x_{n+1}-\ln x_n}{n+1-n}=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\ln\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$(I used the Stolz-Cesaro theorem).
Hence, $L=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$.
Now, in your problem we have $x_n=2n$. By using the theorem above, we easily have that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n] {2n}=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+2}{2n}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log(2n)}$$ 
Since ${\frac{1}{n}\log(2n)}\longrightarrow 0$, then $  {(2n)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \longrightarrow 1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\lim (2n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim e^{\frac{\ln(2n)}{n}}.$$