# Find the limit of $(7^n + 9^n)^{(1/n)}$ when n goes to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I tried this using L' Hopitals rule. But I always get a limit that is not defined.

$$\lim_{n \to\infty}(7^n +9^n)^{(1/n)}$$

Let $$y = (7^n +9^n)^{(1/n)}$$
then take the $log$ of both side,
$$ln(y)= ln((7^n +9^n)^{(1/n)})$$
$$ln(y)= (1/n) * ln(7^n +9^n)$$
$$ln(y) = (ln(7^n +9^n))/n$$

then we find the limit of both side when n goes to $\infty$
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}(ln(y))= \lim_{n \to\infty}((ln(7^n +9^n))/n)$$

we can see the limit of numerator and the denominator is infinity. So, we apply L'Hopitals rule,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(ln(y)) = (1/(7^n +9^n))*(7^n*ln7+ 9^n*ln9) = (7^n*ln7+ 9^n*ln9)/(7^n +9^n)$$

Again this limit is not defined as we get $\infty$ by $\infty$
If I apply L'Hopitals again and the limit of the result will be the same.

Can someone help me to find the answer by L'Hopitals or an Alternative way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit more lengthy, but it is a good general method which is not so widespread.
Using the Cauchy-D'Alembert criterion(see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3159844/629594), we have
$$\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{7^n+9^n}=\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\frac{7^{n+1}+9^{n+1}}{7^n+9^n}=\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\frac{7\cdot\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)^n+9}{\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)^n+1}=9$$

Answer (score 8):

$$\sqrt[n]{9^n+7^n}=9\sqrt[n]{1+\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)^n}\rightarrow9.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$9^{n}<7^{n}+9^{n}<9^{n}+9^{n}=2\cdot 9^{n}$$

$$9<\bigg(7^{n}+9^{n}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}<\bigg(2\cdot 9^{n}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Using Squeeze Theorem

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(7^{n}+9^{n}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}=9.$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, for $a>0$ and $b>0$, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=\max(a,b)$$
In this case, the given limit is equal to $9$ (just as they answered you above).