# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1^k +2^k+\cdots+ n^k},$

Tags: calculus, limits, discrete-mathematics

What is
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1^k +2^k+\cdots+ n^k},$$
where $ k\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Are you asking about limits in general, or that one limit in particular?

Comment: You might want to check out Faulhaber's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), which gives a formula for the expression under the $n$th root.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$1\le 1^k +2^k+\cdots+ n^k\le n^{k+1}$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

When we deal with limits involving the $n^{\text{th}}$ root of an expression, a useful result is this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3159844/629594.
With this in mind, we may write that
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1^k +2^k+\cdots+ n^k}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1^k+2^k+...+(n+1)^k}{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}\stackrel{\text{Stolz-Cesaro}}{=}\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+2)^k}{(n+1)^k}=1$.
The other answer is nicer, because it just uses the squeeze theorem, but I wanted to show that this can roughly be done by applying Stolz-Cesaro two times.